# how to write an arraylist value in an single column using JXL

Tags: java, jxl

how can we write an ArrayList values ('n' numbers) with single column(ms excel) by using jxl

```
ArrayList<String> allRecordCount = scrapAllRecord();
Label EEFL = new Label(1, row, allRecordCount.get(0);
sheet.addCell(new Label(EEFL));
```

allRecordCount have 'n' numbers of values need to write all those values in an single column

Answer (score 0):

using StringUtils and add an separation and insert into specific column

```
ArrayList<String> allRecordCount = scrapAllRecord();
Label EEFL = new Label(7, 3,
StringUtils.join(allRecordCount, ','));
sheet.addCell(new Label(EEFL));
```